# onTouch events in Fragment only registering scrolling

Tags: android, listview, fragment, motionevent

I am listening for onTouch events for my listView (custom PinnedSectionListView), but it seems to only register MotionEvents if I scroll up and down. I primarily need it to respond to taps. If I tap the cells, it does nothing.

In my `OnCreateView` in my fragment I have the following code:

```
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(mContext, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
                int position = mListView.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                if (mAdapter.getItem(position) != null) {
                    onClickListItem(mAdapter.getItem(position));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        mListView.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP");
                    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
                    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action " + event.getAction());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get item click events, you'll want to use `onListItemClick`, which is implemented as part of the [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) interface. So your override would be...

```
@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something when a list item is clicked
}
```

Comment: this method doesn't seem to generate a motion event. How would you detect a double tap on a cell?

Comment: This method is used for detecting a tap on a ListView item, which is what your question asked for.

Comment: If you are wanting to detect a double tap on a list item, I think you can only get the x and y coordinates of the double tap, which you'd then have to manually match up with the coordinates of list items. It's much simpler to use a long press instead of double taps, as the Google UI guidelines suggest.